# Custom API function to add country codes to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am trying to apply a function I made to every row of my data frame, to get the country codes associated with the country. When I test my function individually on countries, it works.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

get_country_codes <- function(countryname){
    
url<-'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/'

url<- paste(url,countryname,sep="")

raw_result=GET(url)
    
    

get_codes_text <- content(raw_result, "text")



get_codes <- fromJSON(get_codes_text)
    


return(get_codes[4])


}
```

This works when I apply the function to any country like this

```
get_country_codes('Andorra')
```

But when I try to apply it over my data frame 'Country' column

```
new_df <- apply(country_data['Country'], 1, function(x) get_country_codes(x))
new_df
```

it mostly gives me NA's.

I'm not sure what is happening with my apply function, I have tested it on countries individually and it works for mostly all of them.

Comment: Is 'Country' a factor rather than a character vector? If that doesn't help you'll need to include some sample data in the question so people can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sapply` :

```
new_df <- sapply(country_data$Country, get_country_codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
new_df <- map(country_data$Country, get_country_codes)
```